# I get an internal error whenever I run the command "msg"

Tags: java, bukkit

I get an internal error every time I run the command without any other arguments. Internal error: https://gyazo.com/f4c16facadf878fad6b00e645b3539c6 // My code:

```
    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("msg")) {

        if (args.length < 1) {

            sender.sendMessage("§cUsage: /msg <player> <msg>");
            return true;
        }

        if (target != null) {

            if (args.length > 1) {

                String msg = "";

                for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++){
                    String arg = (args[i] + " ");
                    msg = (msg + arg);
                }

                target.sendMessage("§b(From§f " + sender.getName() + "§b)§f " + msg);
                sender.sendMessage("§b(To§f " + target.getName() + "§b)§f " + msg);
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (target == null) {

            sender.sendMessage("§cThat player is offline.");
            return true;
```

Comment: Do you have a detailed stacktrace from the server? It will contain information that is highly necessary to help debug this.

Comment: What's in the server console?

Comment: This is the error: http://prntscr.com/qg7mg3

Comment: For the future, please include error messages such as the server console, in the form of code blocks in your post, rather than images. When they're in text format we can easily copy-paste them, and they're more accessible to users who might use some sort of assistive technology or are working on limited bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using `args[0]` in

```
 Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
```

before checking it's lenght, here

```
if (args.length < 1) {

   sender.sendMessage("§cUsage: /msg <player> <msg>");
   return true;
}
```

This might cause `the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

**check if this solves the problem**

```
        if (args.length < 1) {

            sender.sendMessage("§cUsage: /msg <player> <msg>");
            return true;
        }
Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("msg")) {

        if (target != null) {

            if (args.length > 1) {

                String msg = "";

                for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++){
                    String arg = (args[i] + " ");
                    msg = (msg + arg);
                }

                target.sendMessage("§b(From§f " + sender.getName() + "§b)§f " + msg);
                sender.sendMessage("§b(To§f " + target.getName() + "§b)§f " + msg);
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (target == null) {

            sender.sendMessage("§cThat player is offline.");
            return true;
```

Comment: Furthermore, it really should be `if (args.length < 2)`, since both are requried.